# formatCellValue and getCelltype didn't work with apache poi

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-upload, apache-poi

How to get cell value and the type with poi in java ?
My code is look like this

```
 for (Row row : sheet) {
            DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
            Personne per= new Personne();
         asp.setGroupe(df.formatCellValue(row.getCell(2).getCellType()));
}
```

the error is : The method formatCellValue(Cell) in the type DataFormatter is not applicable for the arguments (CellType)

Groupe is  a foreign key type groupe please what i should to do when i removed .getCellType i get this error : 
The method setGroupe(groupe) in the type Personne is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: use asp.setGroupe(df.formatCellValue(row.getCell(2))); because method formatCellValue(Cell cell) accept Cell not CellType

Comment: You need to make two calls, one to get the type, one to format the value

Comment: Gagravarr how to do this please ?

Comment: If you want the cell type, call `cell.getCellType()`. If you want the cell's value, switch on the type and fetch with the appropriate call. If you want "a string that shows what Excel would show for a cell", call `dataformatter.formatCellValue(cell)`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are not using the classes correctly.

Dataformatter.formatCellValue(Cell) requires a Cell as parameter. You are providing a CellType. Furthermore: formatCellValue gives back a String, not a Groupe.

https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html

```
for (Row row : sheet) {
    DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
    Personne per= new Personne();
    df.formatCellValue(row.getCell(2));

    // Don't know what this is...  asp.setGroupe());
}
```

Check the documentation. The errors you see are compile issues. This is normal since you are using the API incorrectly.

Comment: asp = pers instant of my class , pers.setGroupe(df.formatCellValue(row.getCell(2).getCellType())) but i have error

Comment: so what i should to do to get the type who i need

Comment: @ELMANDPURAMINE Take a look at the relevant POI "quick-guide" - for example, [here](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents).